# Create instances of flex custom component by passing in type

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, mxml

In my flex app there are a few custom components. I want to create instance of these components at runtime and assign them properties by reading in a config file.
I know how to read xml and instantiate components, however my question is about being able 
to get the type of the component from the xml attribute and then creating an instance of that type.
My xml looks like this:

Comment: Did you mean to come back and post the XML ?

Comment: using xml to config your components is probably a bad idea, and a holdover from some other language you're used to. Try to do the same thing another way.

Comment: I had the xml. Somehow it disappeared from my posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can instantiate an arbitrary named type through ActionScript's "reflection API":

```
var clazz:Class = Class(getDefinitionByName("class.from.your.xml.file.Name"));
var component:Object = new clazz();
```

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/utils/package.html#getDefinitionByName()

If you get an error about the type not existing, this is because it isn't linked from elsewhere in your application and the compiler only adds classes that are referenced. You can work around this using the following compiler arg:

```
includes class [...]
```

> Links one or more classes to the resulting application SWF file, whether or not those classes are required at compile time.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/compilers_14.html#157203

Comment: I ended up using the above code in combination with passing the class into an instance of the ClassFactory.